# How to set rows value as column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table `tblTags` (Date, Tagindex, Value)

The values in the table are:

```
Date            Tagindex    Value
---------------------------------
2017-10-21         0          21
2017-10-21         1         212
2017-10-21         2          23
2017-10-21         0          34
2017-10-21         1          52
2017-10-21         2          65
```

I want the result as :

```
Date            0    1     2
-------------------------------
2017-10-21      21   212   23
2017-10-21      34    52   65
```

For this I wrote the followring query

```
select * 
from
    (SELECT a.Date, a.Tagindex,a.value
     FROM tblTag a) as p
pivot 
    (max(value)
        for Tagindex in ( [tblTag])
    ) as pvt
```

But I get these errors:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
>
> Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The incorrect value "tblTag" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can use a query like this:

```
;with t as (
  select *
    , row_number() over (partition by [Date],[Tagindex] order by (select 0)) seq
  from tblTag
)
select [Date],
  max(case when [Tagindex] = 0 then [Value] end) '0',
  max(case when [Tagindex] = 1 then [Value] end) '1',
  max(case when [Tagindex] = 2 then [Value] end) '2'
from t
group by [Date], seq;
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82b5ad/3)
[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo - with pivot**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82b5ad/5)

Note: In above query I use `row_number()` function to create a sequence number for each `Date` and `Tagindex`, But the trick is in using `(select 0)` that is a temporary field to use in order by part, that will not trusted to return arbitrary order of inserted rows.So, if you need to achieve a trusted result set; you need to have an extra field like a `datetime` or an auto increment field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tblTag TABLE
(
    [Date] DATE
   ,[TagIndex] TINYINT
   ,[Value] INT
);

INSERT INTO @tblTag ([Date], [TagIndex], [Value])
VALUES ('2017-10-21', 0, 21)
      ,('2017-10-21', 1, 212)
      ,('2017-10-21', 2, 23)
      ,('2017-10-22', 0, 34)
      ,('2017-10-22', 1, 52)
      ,('2017-10-22', 2, 65);

SELECT *
FROM @tblTag
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [Tagindex] IN ([0], [1], [2]) 
) PVT;
```

You need to say exactly [which are the PIVOT columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If you are going to have different values for the `TagIndex` and you cannot hard-coded them, you need to use dynamic PIVOT.

Also, you need to be sure you have a way to group the `tagIndex` values in one row. For example, different date (as in my test data), `ID` column which is marking when a row is inserted or something else (group ID column or date added column).